# Responsive top navigation menu: hamburger not displayed on small screen except on home page

Tags: javascript, css, menu, html5-canvas, responsive

I'm using the W3Schools' responsive top menu. When I shrink the browser window the 'hamburger' menu displays and works on the home page, but not on any of the other four pages.

This is the html code:
<

```
div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <a href="index.html" class="active" title="Applied Ecosystem
                                                    Services, LLC | Providing essential
                                                    environmental services">Home</a>
         <a href="testimonials.html" class="active" title="Client Testimonials">Why
           Clients Retain Me</a>
         <a href="capabilities.html" class="active" title="Providing essential environmental
                                            services">Capabilities</a>
         <a href="library.html" class="active" title="Environmental Regulatory Science
                                       Resource Library">Documents</a>
         <a href="contact.html" class="active" title="Contacting The Environmental Issues
                                       Doctor">Contact me</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         </a>
      </div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  /*  background-color: #008B8B */
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for
   the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close
   the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user
   clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens
   (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
  }
}
```

And this is the javascript:

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when
 * the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

I don't know enough to find why the hamburger menu doesn't display and work on all pages. I look forward to learning why.

Comment: It's a bit hard as we don't see the html of your sub-pages. Are the same css files included in all of those?

Comment: Yes. styles.css is in the css/ directory and used by all pages.